# Android split string from PHP in an array for a AlertDialog

Tags: php, android, string, android-alertdialog

What I'm doing is building an Android app that receives a string using a php script which I can do, but what I can't do is then split that string up using the "\n" and then use that to create an AlertDialog.

I'm recieving this string;

```
    String list = "test 1\ntest 2\ntest 3";
```

I'm then trying to then pipe that into an array using the below. I know I'm miles off but can't seem to find anything about it, could someone point me in the right direction?

```
    String[] tokens = test.split("\n"); 

    final CharSequence[] items = {tokens};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

    alert.show();
```

Comment: It doesn't like the placements of "tokens" when you hover over it in eclipse it says "ype mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to CharSequence". Many thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you creating a new array for the CharSequence? You can just set the tokens array as items:

```
final String[] tokens = test.split("\n"); 
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
    builder.setItems(tokens, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tokens[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

Comment: Derp! That makes sense, I was reading too much into the example on the android dev site Many thanks!